# Why is $[0, 1/4)$ open in $X = [0, 1]$, and why then is it not open in $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

"Let $X = [0, 1]$ with its usual metric (which it inherits from $\mathbb{R}$). Then the subset $[0, 1/4)$ is an open subset of $X$ (but not of course of $\mathbb{R}$)."

Definition:

*A subset $A$ of a metric space $X$ is called open in $X$ if every point of $A$ has an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood which lies completely in $A$.*

I don't understand two things:

1. How can $[0, 1/4)$ be open in $X$, how do we find an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood around $0$ and $1/4$?
2. If it is open in $X$, then why not in $\mathbb{R}$, why can't we use the same $\epsilon$-neighbourhoods we use in $X$?

Comment: You need the notion of relative openness, as $X$ is a metric subspace of $\mathbb{R}.$ Can you intersect $X$ with an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and get $[0,1/4)$ in return?

Comment: Note:  we don't need to find an $\epsilon$-neighborhood around $1/4$, since $1/4\not\in[0,1/4)$

Comment: And how does one find an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of the point $0$, such that this neighbourhood is contained in $X$?

Comment: $[0,1/4($ itself is a $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of $0$. You probably need to freshen up relative topology, see my answer below.

Comment: Note:  $[0,\epsilon)$ is an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $0$ **in $[0,1/4)$** when $\epsilon<1/4$, but it is not such in $\mathbb R$

Comment: Just started a course on Topology, so not much to freshen up. 
So why is [0,1/4) not an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$? Do you have to "approach $0$ from the left" as well in $\mathbb{R}$? Since $(\infty, 0] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What's your definition of $\epsilon$-neighborhood?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$ it would be $(x - \epsilon, x + \epsilon)$ for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: That's what it turns out to be, but I would define an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $x$ in $X$ to be $\{y\in X:|y-x|<\epsilon\}$

Answer (score 2):

By definition of the topology on $[0,1]$, the open sets of $X$ are of the form
$$[0,1]\cap U$$
where $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. So for instance
$$[0,1/4)=[0,1]\cap (-1/4,1/4)$$
is open since $(-1/4,1/4)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.